# Properties of Stopping Sets

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let $S$ be a countable set, and we define a family of sub-$\sigma$-algebras $(F_A)_{A \subseteq S}$ such that $A \subseteq B \Rightarrow \mathcal{F}_A \subseteq \mathcal{F}_B$ for all $A, B \subseteq S$. Let $\zeta$ be a random subset of $S$ (i.e. $\zeta : \Omega \to \mathcal{P}(S)$, and $\{\zeta \subseteq A\} \in \mathcal{F}$ for all $A \subseteq S$). We say that $S$ is a stopping set if $\{\zeta \subseteq A\} \in \mathcal{F_A}$ for all $A \subseteq S$. I want to show that:

1. $\zeta$ is a stopping set $\Leftrightarrow$ $\{\zeta = A\} \in \mathcal{F}_A$ for all $A \subseteq S$.
2. For two stopping sets $\zeta$ and $\eta$, $\zeta \cup \eta$ is a stopping set, but not necessarily $\zeta \cap \eta$.

---

For Q1, the forward direction is straightforward as $S$ is countable, so $A$ is countable. We can simply observe that $\{\zeta = A\} = \{\zeta \subseteq A\} \setminus \bigcup_{a \in A} \{\zeta \subseteq A \setminus \{a\}\} \in \mathcal{F}_A$. The converse is however much less straightforward, as the number of subsets of $A$ may be uncountable (e.g. $A = S$). Since $\sigma$-algebra only guarantees closure for countable unions, I'm unsure how to proceed.

For Q2, the first part is also straightforward, with the observation that $\{\zeta \cup \eta \subseteq A\} = \{\zeta \subseteq A\} \cap \{\eta \subseteq A\}$. I am not sure how to construct a counterexample for the second. I realise this is the case because I do not have a good idea of what random and stopping sets actually are. I would appreciate it if someone can provide me a counterexample to when $\zeta \cap \eta$ is not a stopping set, and also an explanation (or, a link to a place with a good explanation) on what random and stopping subsets are.

Thanks in advance.

---

**LATE EDIT**: This question was reposted on MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344182/properties-of-random-and-stopping-sets) and has been answered.